# symfony2 doctrine2 : create an event that listens for select queries and returns the trace

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine-orm, trace, addeventlistener

With my symfony2/doctrine2 application, there are cases when I have a hard time figurint out where I did not addselect the right entities in my queries, which results in abnormal number of queries.

I am looking forward to build a class that would return the trace for each query I've launched, so I can understand where I need to addselect what.

Questions:

1. is the `postLoad` event of doctrien the right one to do that ? I did
   not found a select event
2. once I am in my eventListener, how can I get the trace from something even without an exception being thrown ?

EDIT :

I managed to modify the profiler.
See how it's done here :

[Symfony2 / Doctrine2 : How to override DebugStack class used in doctrine DataCollector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855412/symfony2-doctrine2-how-to-override-debugstack-class-used-in-doctrine-datacol)

Comment: Isn't the debug toolbar providing enough information for you to use? I know that it does not show from where exactly the queries are being executed, but looking at the generated SQL code you should be able to easily track everything. I've been asked to optimize projects with bizarre amount of queries, and the debug bar really does the job.

Comment: well, I feel it's not optimal. It would be so easy to optimize it with the trace for each query !

Comment: Well, at the very least I can suggest you to take a look at how they created the sql profiler. I am sure you can get some idea from there as a starting point. The full class namespace is: **Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DataCollector\DoctrineDataCollector** and its under vendor **symfony/symfony**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about `SELECT` queries than probably the `postLoad` event is enough.

You can always use `debug_backtrace` to generate the trace without any exceptions.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Then you can log it for further processing.

Comment: nice, that's what I did here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855412/symfony2-doctrine2-how-to-override-debugstack-class-used-in-doctrine-datacol